# Getting error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: java, android, xml

I am facing this problem

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex 'C:\Users\pallab edp.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.2.2\285cb9c666f0f0f3dd8a1be04e1f457eb7b15113\jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar' to 'D:\Android Studio Workspace\GSTIndiaExpertWorkSpace\GST_TEST\GSTINDIAEXPERT_TEST.COM\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\jackson-annotations-2.2.2_0bd3ab626b525d181223d33781533e94a52b5b43'

I have added `defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true}` but till now its not solved my issue please help

Comment: Have you tried deleting the Build folders from project in Explorer. there are two build folders one in directory of your application and one inside app module. Close android studio, delete both of them reopen your project, clean, build it again, hope it will solve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried deleting the Build folders from project in Explorer. there are two build folders one in directory of your application and one inside app module. Close android studio, delete both of them reopen your project, clean, build it again, hope it will solve.

Comment: Yes according to your suggestion I could overcome this problem. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me with rebuild project. In the menu: choose *Build* and then *Rebuild Project*.